# Android how to load videos fast like facebook

Tags: android, video-streaming

I would like to know what design/architecture/solution should I use to load videos in my Android RecyclerView as fast as Facebook does?

- I am currently using https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia EMVideoView to show videos loaded over the web in my ViewHolder. But, loading the video takes time.

Should I show an image over the video while it loads? Am I using the right views?

Comment: are you using the same video to compare your time ?

Comment: I haven't done any time comparison testing... but I believe its more of a user perception issue. Right now, with my EMVideoView, loading a video takes time. I see a progress indicator for a few seconds which is not great compared to Facebook where the videos "seem to load so fast" that while scrolling, I could believe that all these videos are already local on my mobile device. My question relates to what strategy/design can be used to achieve this in Android?